# DotNetOpenAuth setting the popup to do a post instead of a get

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I was able to get the DotNetOpenAuth set up in my MVC3 project. (Took a long time, but finally was able to get all the missing pieces.)

However, now I'm getting a 414 error from Google that the request URL is too long. I found that google is saying in those cases the request should be a post and the issue would be gone. I was wondering if there was a way to construct post instead of a get when the popup windows are being pre-loaded?

I'm using nerddinner as my stepping stone, and have used the code in the AuthController code to get the url's preloaded. http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70027#952619

Is it possible to do a post in those popups? Or how did people get around the 414 error for Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth already 'upgrades' long URLs from GET to POST, and does so at the 2048 character length threshold.  There have occasionally been reports that this threshold is too high, and it is adjustable by web.config file setting.  However, I don't think that adjusts the AJAX .js file on the client (yet).

If you will please [file a ticket](https://github.com/aarnott/dotnetopenid/issues?authenticity_token=846b3729dac39440434c60781acb391ed0af0645&request_uri=/AArnott/dotnetopenid/issues&milestone=&labels=&state=closed) describing this problem, we can get a maintenance release of DotNetOpenAuth out that resolves this issue.

FYI the .js file is found in the DotNetOpenAuth project source code  and is called `OpenIdRelyingPartyControlBase.js`.  But since it compiles as a resource into the dotnetopenauth.dll and downloads to the web browser directly from there, it makes it inconvenient for you to fix with an adjusted threshold.

Comment: Thanks @andrew. I have added the ticket: https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/issues/51